# Is it possible to declare an array size and assign in the same line?

Tags: c#, arrays

Is it possible to declare the size of an array and assign to the first element in the array in the same line?

```
var newRecord = new RecordModel
{
  Artist = "KRS-ONE",
  Title = "Return of the Boom Bap",
  Tracks = new int[NumberOfTracks] // Is there a way to assign here?
}

// Currently doing it this way
newRecord.Tracks[0] = 2;
```

Comment: You can't do that if `NumberOfTracks` is a variable. If you have the values available in another array you can directly assign it. `Tracks = anotherarray`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize the array size and values inline, but you have to set all its values

```
//This works
var numbers = new int[3]{1,2,3};

//This doesn't, "An array initializer of length '3' is expected"
var numbers = new int[3]{1};
```

Comment: Ahh .. I see what your saying. I will have to stick to the way I am doing it because at initialization time I do not have the other values in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use a list.

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Comment: Indeed it would be better and easier to use a list. However, it is someone else's class and I cannot change it.